# Eigen: Packet access and Replicate

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I'm new to Eigen and I'm trying to understand the semantics of Packet Access in the context of a simple Replicate expression that replicates a vector to (say) 4 columns.

Currently neither the Replicate expression, nor the unary evaluator for it enables packet access and I'm trying to see, for simple cases at least, if I could make some changes so that when I assign to a matrix, the underlying operations can get vectorized.

I tried a hack (which is definitely the wrong way to go about this) in CoreEvaluators.h:1242 where I propagate the PacketAccessBit on the Replicate's ArgType and that generates vectorized code but I'd like to figure out what the right way to do this is.

```
template<typename ArgType, int RowFactor, int ColFactor> 
struct unary_evaluator<Replicate<ArgType, RowFactor, ColFactor> >
  : evaluator_base<Replicate<ArgType, RowFactor, ColFactor> >
{
 [...]
    Flags = (evaluator<ArgTypeNestedCleaned>::Flags & (HereditaryBits|LinearAccessMask|PacketAccessBit) & ~RowMajorBit) | (traits<XprType>::Flags & RowMajorBit),
 [...]
```

Comment: SO is not the right place to discuss that, this should be reported to http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/.

Comment: Thanks, I'll request a bugzilla account and move the discussion there